# Oracle Database Backup in DBeaver

Tags: oracle, dbeaver

I am new to Oracle databases. I have installed DBeaver (never used this before too) to connect to the database.

I have created a connection (which I believe is called database) and now I am able to see the database tables and everything. How do I take the backup of the Oracle Database in DBeaver so I can use it locally for test purposes before making any change on live database?

I can't find any option to take the backup of connection/database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do a proper backup of your Oracle Database, you should use the oracle provided utility, Recovery Manager. It's a command line interface that's called from your DB server shell prompt via 'RMAN'

You can also use Data Pump to export all or part of a database that can be used to import to another database...not really used for recovery of an existing database.

I'm not aware of your tool having interfaces for either of these Oracle features.

You might not need a backup at all for your needs, take a look at [Oracle Flashback Technology](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/high-availability/flashback.html).

Answer (score 1):

DBeaver does not support oracle database export import. See details here:
https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Backup-Restore/

You need to run the ***sqlplus*** tool to create a folder where oracle is going to import/export database dumps. Login should happen as sys as sysdba and enter the password you previously entered during database server installation. Example:
**sqlplus sys/[your password] as sysdba**
[image]

After you successfully logged into sqlplus run the following command (don't forget to set to a different folder that you prefer to use):
**create or replace directory DATA_PUMP_DIR as 'D:\Database Backups';**

Once this is done exit from sqlplus and enter the following command into the command line (again no sqlplus should be used here)

**expdp sys/[your password]@localhost:1521/[listener name] file=your-database-dump-file.dmp owner=[your schema]**

Once this is done and finished you can zip your database dump if you would like to upload it somewhere else. (I had 9 GB dump and the zipped size was 1.6 GB)

Comment: thanks, @Richárd Baldauf